# How do I write AppleScript to perform the actions on the main window of GarageBand?

Tags: applescript, audio, garageband

I am an applescript noob and and I am hoping to control GarageBand with my MIDI foot control so I can play my electric guitar as I press the foot control to stop, start recording etc. on GarageBand. I know GarageBand doesn't allow for a full set of MIDI controls, and Logic does, but until I buy a newer macbook with Logic Pro, this is going to have to do. For this, I use a software called MIDIPipe which stands in between my MIDI control (Behringer FCB1010) and GarageBand. The MIDI is connected in my case to a PreSonus USB audio interface Studio 26c which is connected to my macbook via USB. (The Presonus Studio 26c USB audio interface has MIDI input and output.)

Anyway,what I want to do is when specific MIDI foot control keys are pressed, I want to be able to (a) Start the recording, and (b) Stop the recording. The main window `keystroke`s are "R" and "0" respectively. But it does not seem to work when I execute this:

```
(* 

   on runme (message) is the callback for the MIDIPipe processing, effectively "catches"
   the MIDI commands from my foot control and executes System Events on the macbook.
*)
on runme (message)
tell application "GarageBand"
    activate
    if (item 1 of message = 192) and (item 2 of message = 0) then tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "R"
end tell
end runme
```

But that does not seem to be doing anything (it compiles fine). I expected in this case to start recording in Garageband, but all a foot press of button 0 on the foot control does is that it activates Garageband. I tried other key codes, e.g., 30 for right square bracket and it does what I expect it to do (see https://support.apple.com/guide/garageband/main-window-shortcuts-gbnd58362a62/mac)--in this case, scroll through a list of amps.

Any insights into what I could be doing to make GarageBand start recording?